# Vagrant ssh doesn't display command prompt

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a computer that runs Windows 8.1 and for some projects I use Vagrnat and VirtualBox, however after upgrading VirtualBox and Vagrant, after running Vagrant ssh, vagrant doesn't display the command prompt. I thought that may be it's a problem related with old boxes so I've create a new VM but the results is the same.

[As can be seen below, some commands return results and everything is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kKoQ.jpg):

[image]

[sudo -i returns me that stdin: is not a tty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MaL1.jpg):

[image]

Could you have a look please and give me an idea about how can I solve this problem?

Comment: this seems to be a known issue with gitbash, you can use default command line from windows and it should work

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri for your answer, if I don't find an another solution I will try that.

Comment: @jww thanks for your reply, I have asked this question in unix.stackexchange.com now, so I will delete this question shortly

Comment: Have same problem.  What is a solution to this problem?